# How to fix GC Overlimit issue in Scala?

Tags: postgresql, scala, garbage-collection

We have queried the  Postgres database and lots of DB query are firing using multiple joins and then manipulating the data and returning it according to time given start and end date,

I made a change today earlier we are fetching let say department and per department count of students i.e deptName and count. What I made a change today instead of count, I get the user's roll number i.e dept, roll no

After running I started getting

```
[warn] 6.648 seconds of the last 10 seconds were spent in garbage collection. You may want to increase the project heap size using `-Xmx` or try a different gc algorithm, e.g. `-XX:+UseG1GC`, for better performance.
[warn] 104.038 seconds of the last 10 seconds were spent in garbage collection. You may want to increase the project heap size using `-Xmx` or try a different gc algorithm, e.g. `-XX:+UseG1GC`, for better performance.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded[HikariPool-1 housekeeper] WARN  c.z.h.p.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=1m32s440ms405µs146ns). 
[warn] 15.884 seconds of the last 10 seconds were spent in garbage collection. You may want to increase the project heap size using `-Xmx` or try a different gc algorithm, e.g. `-XX:+UseG1GC`, for better performance.

    at io.inbox.reporting.utility.Utility$.$anonfun$clubData$8(Utility.scala:153)
    at io.inbox.reporting.utility.Utility$$$Lambda$8631/40350775.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.$anonfun$map$2(TraversableLike.scala:827)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$Lambda$7442/1915747196.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:826)
    at io.inbox.reporting.utility.Utility$.$anonfun$clubData$6(Utility.scala:147)
    at io.inbox.reporting.utility.Utility$$$Lambda$8629/1726674536.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:338)
    at io.inbox.reporting.utility.Utility$.$anonfun$clubData$5(Utility.scala:146)
    at io.inbox.reporting.utility.Utility$$$Lambda$8628/705087722.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:338)
    at io.inbox.reporting.utility.Utility$.clubData(Utility.scala:145)
    at io.inbox.reporting.report.WeeklyReport.$anonfun$getReportsByClaim$25(WeeklyReport.scala:100)
    at io.inbox.reporting.report.WeeklyReport$$Lambda$8618/186162453.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$Lambda$8045/150744459.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$$Lambda$7429/1893629511.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175)
[INFO] [03/16/2021 17:01:24.566] [inbox-reporting-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(inbox-reporting)] Request timeout encountered for request [POST /reporting/data Strict(150 bytes)]
```

After browsing, I came up with adding java options so I added following options but issue didn't resolve.

```
javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xms512M", "-Xmx1024M", "-Xss1M", "-XX:MaxPermSize=1024M", "-XX:+UseG1GC", "-XX:ConcGCThreads=2", "-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=1")
```

Please advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the command with increase memory. You can use the below commands. you can try one of them.

```
<command> -mem 5000
<command> -J-Xmx4G -J-Xms4G
```